# Delete lines in a txt file by taking patterns from another file

Tags: text-processing

I have two txt files :

file1.txt:

```
user1@domain.fr  
user2@domain.fr  
user3@domain.fr  
user4@domain.fr  
...
```

file2.txt:

```
user2@domain.fr  
user4@domain.fr
```

fileIwouldhave.txt:

```
user1@domain.fr  
user3@domain.fr  
...
```

I'd like to delete addresses in file2.txt to file1.txt.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give `grep` a file containing a list of patterns to match (or not), and reverse the match:

```
grep -vFx -f file2.txt file1.txt
```